# Karnaugh map -explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am trying to understand karnaugh-learn. I was trying to solve multiple question on exercises and I failed.
I know that, you would like something specific to show you and to answer it based on that, but what I want to understand is the logic behind Karnaugh.
I am trying to solve logic gates with Karnaugh. I don't get.
I would like to help me understand it or to give me information where I can find it.
I want to be simple so I will understand it. If you could give me some links or explain me how it is working I would be grateful.
I repeat that I know that my question is sound "off topic" but it is not.
I find it very hard to find information on learning it. I check similar questions here and nothing good came from.
If you could help me to give me links, or to explain me step by step here it will be good for me and everyone who is searching to find about it.
I believe there are a lot of guys who are searching about it and they can't get it or find anything about it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO5alU6PpSU

Comment: Use google.com wisely. You will find what you are searching for as long as you are not lazy to surf thru tons of links that pop up.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Wikipedia article about Karnaugh maps, or doing a Google search? What part are you finding hard to understand?

Answer (score 2):

K-maps are based on only one property:

$$AB+A\mathop{\overline{B}}=A$$

This property is extended, for example, to

$$A\mathop{\overline{B}}C+ABC=AC$$

or more complicated cases like:

$$AB\mathop{\overline{C}}\mathop{\overline{D}}+A\mathop{\overline{B}}\mathop{\overline{C}}\mathop{\overline{D}}+AB\mathop{\overline{C}}D+A\mathop{\overline{B}}\mathop{\overline{C}}D=A\mathop{\overline{C}}$$

Consider a Boolean expression represented as a sum-of-products. If we represent each product in a cell, **the key is to map the products in a way that adjacent cells have only one variable that is complemented**. By this way some rules are defined. You can safely (without errors) apply these rules no matter how complicated the expression is, and you will always get the right answer.