# I can't get the equation of a karnaugh map

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

**MD\F 0    1**
**00   0    1**

**01   0    1**

**11   1    1**

**10   0    0**

this is a karnaugh map.

Now , I take in horizontal  1 1 .
As a result I have  M*D.
The F is 0 if we see that it means NOT F and we have 1 so F it remains F.
The F I can erase it ,is that right?
I have the equation for horizontal

`M*D + ..`

After this,I want  after +  of that equation to fill it with the vertically the 1 1 I have.
As we see vertically I have 1.As a result we have F.
that means our equation goes like this

M*D + F

After this I feel I don't make it right.I look at MD in the first row are

```
     M D      and we have F
     0 0                  1
```

so it is not M  NOT D.Lets write it M' D'

for the second row 01 of the MD
it is 01 and in the vertically we have 1.
NOT M *D ,lets write this M'*D

that comes to this
the equation  is
M*D +  F(M'D' * M'*D).
I simplify the equation so it is

```
M*D +F*M'
```

Is right the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  $$MD+F\mathop{\overline{M}}$$ is the right answer.

The upper vertical group 11 is for M=0 and F=1. You do not consider D since it is the variable that is changing state inside the group.

Check this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/555144/254042

You do not need to rethink the Boolean simplification properties when using K-maps. You apply rules and get the simplified expression otherwise it would be useless.